# Sequential Bertrand competition Nash equilibrium when marginal costs are zero

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, competition

How do I find the Nash equilibrium in sequential Bertrand competition between 2 firms if both their marginal costs are zero?

Comment: I am voting to close this homework question as off-topic.